# I need to extract I'd from a Google drive urls with sed, gawk or grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

URLs:

```
1. https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export=download
2. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
3. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py?usp=sharing
```

I need a single regex for these all urls.
This is what I tried to use but didn't get expected results.

```
sed -E 's/.*\(folders\)?\(id\)?=?\/?(.*)&?.*/\1/'
```

Expected results:

```
0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
```

Comment: Yes it was I updated it please look

Comment: `grep -Po 'id=\K[[:alnum:]-]*' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your own code updated:

```
$ cat file
1. https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export=download
2. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
3. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py?usp=sharing

$ sed -E 's@.*(folders/|id=)([^?&]+).*@\2@' file
0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py

$ sed -E 's@.*(folders/|id=)([^?&]+).*@\2@' file | uniq
0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
```

And yours updated to `sed -E 's@.*(folders/|id=)(.*)(\?|&|$).*@\2@'` would work on GNU sed.
You are using `-E`, so no need to escape group quotes `()`, and `|` means `OR`.
When matching literal `?`, you need to escape it.
And the separator of `sed` can change to other character, which is `@` here.
Note `uniq` will only remove adjacent duplicates, if there're duplicates in different places, change it to `sort -u` instead.

A `GNU grep` solution :

```
$ grep -Poi '(id=|folders/)\K[a-z0-9_-]*' file
0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
```

Also these two give same results, but are more accurate than above shorter `sed` one:

```
sed -E 's@.*(folders/|id=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]*).*@\2@'
sed -E 's@.*(folders/|id=)([[:alnum:]_-]*).*@\2@'
```

Btw, `+` means one or more occurances, `*` means zero or more.

A GNU `awk` version (removes duplicates at the same time):

```
awk 'match($0,".*(folders/|id=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)",m){if(!a[m[2]]++)print m[2]}' file
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187155/discussion-on-answer-by-tiw-i-need-to-extract-id-from-a-google-drive-urls-with).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/uc\?id=[^&]*|folders\/[^?]*/){value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/.*=|.*\//,"",value);print value}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Outputs from urls above:

Comment: 1. 0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export 2. No output. 3. 1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py?usp

Comment: @Rohit, plesae check now and let me know? It is working fine for me.

Comment: Nice one without pipes.

Comment: Working now looks like my awk version was ancient and it's a nice answer with awk

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/.*(id=|folders\/)([^&?/]*).*/\2/' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `.*(id=|folders\/)`: after any characters(`.*`) followed by `id=` or `folders/`
- `([^&?/]*)`: search and capture any characters except `&`, `?` and `/`
- `\2`: using backreference, matching string is replaced with the second captured text`([^&?/]*)`

**Edit:**

To remove duplicate url, just pipe the command to `sort` then to `uniq`(because `uniq` just removes adjacent duplicate lines, you may want to `sort` the list before):

```
sed -E 's/.*(id=|folders\/)([^&?/]*).*/\2/' file | sort | uniq
```

As @Tiw suggests in edit, you can also pipe to a single command by using `sort` with the `-u` flag:

```
sed -E 's/.*(id=|folders\/)([^&?/]*).*/\2/' file | sort -u
```

Comment: Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat rohit.txt
1. https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export=download
2. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
3. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py?usp=sharing
$ perl -lne ' s/.*\/.*..\/(.*)$/$1/g; s/(.*id=)//g; /(.+?)(&|\?|$)/ and print $1 ' rohit.txt
0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
1TkLq5C7NzzmbRjd7VGRhauNT9Vaap-Py
$
```